# Google Endpoints - Invalid Token, allowed_client_id using token from OAuth2.0 Playground

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, oauth2-playground

So in my google cloud project I generated a Web Client ID, and follow the steps in 
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/oauth_playground
to get the authentication token.

In my `@endpoints.api(allowed_client_ids=)` I've put the client id inside it. Then in OAuth2 playground I sent a http request using the authentication token which I have acquired (e.g: `Bearer ya29.bwL-f-hz-wcxFq_i-IlEQaJDiinwIP7ad7CaZoRkJRdGrsxxs4Wc9ZeNOgVlhD69zOQk`) to the API.

But the problem is, it did not recognize the token, and said it is an invalid token. To compare with, I put `endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID` together inside the `allowed_clients_ids=`, and when I tested it using API Explorer it just works. So am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you specify any particular scopes in the playground? Can you paste logs from the failed request?

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords that's the scopes that I put inside. As for the logs, it is not necessarily fail, I just put `if endpoints.get_current_user() is None: raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException('')`

Answer (score 0):

You have specify your own client id and client secret. see this
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GEa0.png)

Comment: yeah I did enter the generated one from my API Credentials